# Partitioning an SD card through ADB (Android Debugging Bridge)

Tags: android, adb, android-8.0-oreo, lg

I've been trying to do this for 3 days now but i can't seem to get this to work.

So the gist of it is, I have an LG G6 running Android 8.0, with a 128Gb micro-SD card, I'm running out of internal space, and apparently LG and Samsung remove the adoptable storage feature from their android versions, I found a turn around to this which was to use ADB to partition the SD drive myself, and getting it to behave as internal memory, at first I had an issue with ADB even noticing my device, which I fixed by enabling USB tethering.

Past that everything seems to be going well, do the partition and reboot my phone,(speaking of which SD card is only detected after a reboot if I physically eject it and put it back in) all looks fine as per the screenshots

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX2oJ.jpg

(I was told memory misrepresentation was normal) until I get to the migrate data option which ALWAYS crashes the settings app, on top of that when I plug my phone into my computer I can only see the default internal storage of my device without any added memory.

I've reached a dead end and would appreciate anything at this point, even alternatives if you'd recommend I do something else (rooting or other methods i don't know about). Below are the sources I followed for this process, thanks in advance and if I missed any info let me know.

https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/

https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-format-microsd-cards-as-internal-storage?fbclid=IwAR1pgqf6Ti2rSf_hbiyqLl0HufPewlPCHYmfBcfEzq_XRMhKxevwwq_mk28

https://www.modaco.com/news/android/heres-how-to-configure-adoptable-storage-on-your-s7-s7-edge-r1632/

Commands i entered by order as requested: 
adb shell
sm list-disks
sm partition disk:179,0 private

And yes 179,0 IS the disk name on my phone as far as i can tell

Comment: It would probably help your cause if you list all the adb shell commands you used in order. Referencing guides does not show what you did because a step might have been skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I think that after the sm partition disk there is one thing that you didnt do. That is, sm set-force-adoptable false
After this jsut restart your phone and its gonna work most prob.